# Помогите, как спарсить текст из определенного тега<span></span>

Tags: python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как спарсить текст из **title** в классе `class="tooltip water-now"`

```html
<div class="weather-now-info">
        <div class="thermometer" id="thermometer">
            <div class="thermometer-numbers">
            <div class="thermometer-scale">
            <span></span>
            <em></em>
    </div>
    <p>
        <span>Сейчас</span>
        <em class="tooltip" title="время в Москве"></em>
        <b>21:16, 23 апр</b>
    </p>
    <div id="weather-now-number">+11<span>°</span>
    </div>
    <span class="wi n200 tooltip" id="weather-now-icon" title="Частично облачно"></span><a 
    class="tooltip water-now" href="//world-weather.ru/pogoda/russia/moscow/water/" 
    title="Температура воды">+4°</a></div>
```

Comment: soup.find('span', class_='wi n200 tooltip')['title']

Comment: @СергейШашко , спасибо большое за ответ.